# When I try to create Hibernate.cfg.xml file I am getting this error shown in screenshot, kindly help me solve this

Tags: java

[hibernate.cfg.xml file in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQqdU.jpg)

Upon careful examination of the error messages, it became evident that certain essential elements—namely, 'hibernate configuration,' 'property,' and 'session factory'—are required within the Hibernate configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml). Despite referencing tutorials on platforms such as YouTube, replicating the process proved challenging, and I encountered difficulty in generating this configuration file seamlessly. I am actively seeking guidance and solutions to rectify this issue and ensure the accurate creation of the hibernate.cfg.xml file in alignment with established best practices.

Comment: Please copy the text into the question - don't link or post screenshots.